# Obtener los ids del sistema con c#

Tags: c#

Tengo un problema tratando de obtener algunos de los identificadores de la computadora.

Tengo dos clases para obtener los identificadores.

RegHelper:

```
public static string readStringValue(string regKey, string regValue)
{
    string result;
    try
    {
        result = (string)Registry.GetValue(regKey, regValue, "");
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        result = "";
    }
    return result;
}
```

RegistryValues:

```
internal class RegistryValues
{
    public static string defenderIDKey()
    {
        return "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows Defender\\Signature Updates";
    }

    public static string defenderIDValue()
    {
        return "SignatureCategoryID";
    }
}
```

En el formulario de windows tengo la llamada a esos datos:

```
textBox1.Text = RegHelper.readStringValue(RegistryValues.defenderIDKey(),RegistryValues.defenderIDValue());
```

La carpeta del proyecto está en "archivos del sistema(x86)".

También ejecuto el programa como administrador, pero todavía no me muestra el identificador.

En el textBox tiene que mostrar la cadena de texto del identificador.
Aclaro que no son todas las llamadas, solo algunos identificadores no me los muestra.

Este es una captura de algunos identificadores que intento mostrar (El programa se ejecuta como administrador).

[image: Captura]

Agradecería mucho que pudieran ayudarme a arreglarlo.

Comment: Cual identificador?  El nombre de DNS?  El nombre de Windows?  El fabricante?  El modelo?

Comment: El defender ID. Pero ese es para mostrar uno primero. Luego que lo muestre voy a agregar muchos.